# submit “multipart/form-data” form using ajax + cakephp

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp

Is there a way to submit “multipart/form-data” forms with CakePHP + Ajax + jQuery ?

When I submit the form using Ajax in my CakePHP application, I get all data from the form but not the file that I choose to upload using file control.

This is my code:

```
    function save_option(id)
    {
       $.ajax({

            type        : "post",
            url         : site_url + "lists/save_option/",              
            data        : $("#option_form_"+id).serialize(),
            success     : function(response) {              
                //on success
            },
            error       : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }

       });

    }
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't submit files via ajax (generally) due to security restrictions.

However, you can use JS in conjunction with an iframe to get a similar effect. See here for a tutorial : http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Comment: Thanks a ton for the link to a solution...I was suspicious about this initially but now I am sure that submitting files via ajax is not possible. Another solution that I came across - http://atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/ - though it basically uses same concept of iframe as you pointed out.